# Merge [brew] and [brewmp]

Tags: discussion, tags

Since [bfontaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/735926/bfontaine) is making a bit of cleanup with the [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew) misused in place of [homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homebrew), I made a little search and it seems that [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew) is correctly used only 3 times without [brewmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brewmp).

Also, in MacOs, when you want to use Homebrew you type something like:

```
brew something
```

Which leads to a lot of tagging error...

So, could we merge [brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brew) and [brewmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brewmp) or do they make sense as they are now?